# Google Spreadsheets; OAuth Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, oauth, urlfetch, google-data-api

I am getting an "OAuth Error (line 378, file "Code")" error when I try to run this script.

This script gathers data from a Google Form, runs calculations (which I have deleted to save space), opens a Template Spreadsheet, puts the data in the spreadsheet and e-mails as a PDF (without gridlines).

So I have a few questions

-Should I be putting my Google Apps login and password in the oauthConfig.setConsumerKey and setConsumerSecret?  I tried using "anonymous" but kept getting an "Authorization is required to perform that action" error.

-Do you see anything that I need to change to correct the OAuth Error?

```
      var docTemplate = "0AgNhg8MX8TfDdHlrd3VyU0oybWhHSlBPRlU3LWlGaUE";
      var docName = "Motion Control Report";

    function formSubmitCreate(e) {
      //Variables
      //I've removed a bunch of formulas and variables, I have confirmed that all of this is correct

      //Template Info
      var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate).makeCopy(docName+' for
'+userName+" "+userTimeStamp).getId();
      var copyDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copyId);
      var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSheet();

      copyBody.getRange(1, 2).setValue(userName);
      //Imports a bunch of other values to the spreadsheet, removed to save space

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();

      //Save as PDF and send e-mail
      var pdf = spreadsheetToPDF(copyId);

      var subject = "Motion Control Report - " + userProjectName + " - " +userName;
      var body = userName;
      MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {bcc: "matt@mocoautomation.com", htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

    }

    ////////////////////
    function spreadsheetToPDF(key) {

      var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("spreadsheets");
      var scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"

      oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("myusername");
      oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("password");
      oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
      oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");

      oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");


      var requestData = {
        "oAuthServiceName": "spreadsheets",
        "oAuthUseToken": "always",
      };
      ///GETTING OAuth ERROR FOR THIS LINE
      var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="+key+"&fmcmd=12&size=7&fzr=false&portrait=true&fitw=true&locale=en_GB&gid=0&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=false",
requestData).getBlob().setName("MotionReport");

      return pdf;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be specifying your username and password in your code. The key/secret to use is `anonymous`. Replace with the following two lines of code -

```
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
```

Comment: Arun, thanks for the help.  /n                                                       I made those changes and now I get this error message "Attachment has no content. (line 355, file "Code")".                                   Line 355 refers to; "MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {bcc: "matt@mocoautomation.com", htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});"                                                                     Is the pdf not being made or passed back and forth correctly?

Comment: Thats worth opening a separate thread on but you should use the Logger.log function to debug your code to see if its empty or not.